# doctrine2 merge object with relation

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have an entity with a OneToMany relation to itself (note that it uses single table inheritance).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string", length=30)
 **/
abstract class PlatformPost
{
    // [...]

    /**
     * @var PlatformPost
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PlatformPost", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @var PlatformPost[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PlatformPost", mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"ALL"})
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $comments;

    // [...]
}
```

I create this entity from an api and then persist it. If it already exists i use `$em->merge($post)` to update it.

This only kind of works. The entity I get from that method is exactly like I want it but doctrine does not update the foreign key of the comments. If I query the post again the comment array still contains the old entities which should have been deleted.

A quick solution would be to remove all comments before merging but i'd like a better solution.